# Why does the BigFraction class in the Apache-Commons-Math library return incorrect division results?

Tags: java, biginteger, apache-commons-math

In the spirit of using existing, tested and stable libraries of code, I started using the [Apache-Commons-Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/) and its [`BigFraction` class](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/BigFraction.html) to perform some rational calculations for an Android app I'm writing called RationalCalc.

It works great for every task that I have thrown at it, except for one nagging problem.  When dividing certain `BigFraction` values, I am getting incorrect results.

If I create a `BigFraction` with the inverse of the divisor and multiply instead, I get the same incorrect answer but perhaps that is what the library is doing internally anyway.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The division works correctly with a `BigFraction` of 2.5 but not 2.51, 2.49, etc...

**[UPDATE]**

This was indeed a bug in the apache-commons-math 2.0 libraries.  The bug is fixed in v.2.1.

It is now listed in the Fixed Issues section of the bug tracker:

[When multiplying two BigFraction objects with numerators larger than will fit in an java-primitive int the result of BigFraction.ZERO is incorrectly returned.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-340).

Thanks to @BartK for attempting to reproduce the issue and setting me on the right track.

**[/UPDATE]**

```
// *** incorrect! ***
BigFraction one = new BigFraction(1.524);
//one: 1715871458028159 / 1125899906842624

BigFraction two = new BigFraction(2.51);
//two: 1413004383087493 / 562949953421312

BigFraction three = one.divide(two);
//three: 0

Log.i("solve", three.toString());
//should be 0.607171315  ??
//returns 0


// *** correct! ****
BigFraction four = new BigFraction(1.524);
//four: 1715871458028159 / 1125899906842624

BigFraction five = new BigFraction(2.5);
//five: 5 / 2

BigFraction six = four.divide(five);
//six: 1715871458028159 / 2814749767106560

Log.i("solve", six.toString());
//should be 0.6096  ??
//returns 0.6096
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe an overflow, because the product becomes slightly larger than a long.

Comment: @starblue had a quick look; internally, `BigFraction` appears to use `BigInteger` s to store numerator and denominator, so it's not a *straightforward* overflow

Comment: @starblue, I thought about it being an overflow but wouldn't it make sense for the BigFraction class to throw an exception if that were the case.  Also, I chose to use the BigFraction class specifically because it advertised / implied that it did not have problems with overflow.  That made me think that perhaps it was a bug.  I would say that I'm a fairly experienced programmer so I've been around long enough to know that its usually me making a mistake!  :)

Comment: No, it should just use BigInteger correctly. Since int and long overflow silently it is hard to avoid mistakes w.r.t. overflow, I've had that many times when solving Project Euler problems. In this case, if you really want to know you should debug it, it is open source after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing `double`'s in the constructors lead to round-off errors. Using exact numerators and denominators will result in the expected outcome:

```
public class CommonsMathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigFraction one = new BigFraction(1524, 1000);
        System.out.println("one   = " + one);

        BigFraction two = new BigFraction(251, 100);
        System.out.println("two   = " + two);

        BigFraction three = one.divide(two);
        System.out.println("three = " + three);

        BigFraction four = new BigFraction(1524, 1000);
        System.out.println("four  = " + four);

        BigFraction five = new BigFraction(5, 2);
        System.out.println("five  = " + five);

        BigFraction six = four.divide(five);
        System.out.println("six   = " + six + " = " + six.bigDecimalValue());
    }
}
```

produces:

```
one   = 381 / 250
two   = 251 / 100
three = 762 / 1255
four  = 381 / 250
five  = 5 / 2
six   = 381 / 625 = 0.6096
```

EDIT

By the way, I could not reproduce your output. Using Commons-Math 2.1, the following:

```
BigFraction one = new BigFraction(1.524);
BigFraction two = new BigFraction(2.51);
BigFraction three = one.divide(two);
System.out.println(three.toString() + " = " +three.doubleValue());
```

does not produce `0` as you said, but prints:

```
1715871458028159 / 2826008766174986 = 0.6071713147410359
```

Comment: +1 because this will probably be *useful* for asker to know - but nonetheless, in the original question, once we've got the `BigFraction` s we do, dividing them still shouldn't return zero, should it?

Comment: @Aakash, true, I looked over that, so had another look at it, see my edit.

Comment: regardless of whether I instantiate the BigFraction with a double or by providing the equivalent numerator/denominator, I get the same error.  Your mention of Commons-Math 2.1 and not being able to reproduce the problem piqued my interest so I checked the version number of the commons-math jar that I am using.  It is 2.0 -- perhaps this is a bug and has been fixed.  I will upgrade to 2.1, run my unit tests and report back the results.